# Employees profiles don't show up in "Who'll you work with" section of company page

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

We have set up a a [company page](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/leonidasoy) and invited our employees to join the team. However, only two of us are currently visible in the *Who you'll work with* -section. The people invited have clicked the link, and they see our company in the *Company pages* -section in *Settings -> Developer Story Preferences*. They have made a public link and filled their developer stories.

What more is required for their profiles to show up?

Comment: Looking into this now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had an outstanding bug in the backlog for developer story that we didn't get to before launch. I've addressed it now; you can now see all the profiles on your company page.

Thanks for the report!