# Company selection behaves unexpectedly

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, developer-story

I am trying to add this company (https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/active-cues) in which I am currently employed in my developer story, however whenever I write the company name, it does not display me the one with 2 members already, but instead creates a new one on the spot.

For some reason, it uses https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/lists/69510/active-cues?storyType=1 instead of the actual existing one.

I tried using the Company ID in the editing mode to make sure that I'd target the existing page, but that does not seem to work.

Any solution to this?

My dev story: https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/2362433

Comment: think this is [status-bydesign], both were never linked. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/339128 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/345022

Comment: How am I supposed to list myself under the correct company, then?

Comment: According to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/336277, the admin of the company page in [jobs] need to manually send an invite link to you.